# Error message when using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation

$2y^2 + 2 x y y' + x y^3 y' - 2 x^2 (y')^2 + x^2 y y'' = 0$

I tried

```
DSolve[2 y[x]^2 + 2 xy[x] Derivative[1][y][x] + 
x y[x]^3 Derivative[1][y][x] - 2 x^2 Derivative[1][y][x]^2 + 
x^2 y[x] (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

but I get the error message

```
Attributes::notfound: Symbol DSolveDispatchODE not found.
```

Comment: Likely due to a missing space in xy[x]. When I replace it with x y[x], after some time Mathematica returns the command, which means that Mathematica can not find a closed form for the solution (which then very likely does not  exist).

Comment: the way you have expressed the second derivative is not correct, although that might be a typo here.  ( Try `D[y[x],{x,2}]` )  (Fixing that and the space it just returns unevaluated indicating, not surprisingly, that `DSolve` doesn't know how to solve it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
eq = 2 y[x]^2 + 2 x*y[x]*y'[x] + x*y[x]^3*y'[x] - 2 x^2*y'[x]^2 +x^2*y[x]*y''[x] == 0;
DSolve[eq, y, x]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it just outputted as DSolve [....]

Comment: I think it means that mathematica couldn't solve that analytically, with NDSolve you see this answer: y-> InterpolatingFunction